# Changed order of blocks in responsive design won't work on smartphone?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to figure out a bit of a puzzle that I ran into while I was coding my first (!) responsive website.

In the mobile version I have set up media queries so that the "nav" element moves downward, right before the footer - while on large screens it'd normally be set right after the header.

I used flexbox like this

```
#layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and assignated order 3 to footer and 2 to nav - on my computer, resizing the browser, it works gold.

However when I test it on my smartphone (iPhone3, running Safari) it ignores the  instruction totally? Is there any way I can make this work on mobile devices, not just low-res?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 3;
  }
  .nav {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
<header style="background-color:red; width:100%; height:100px;">Placeholder</header>

<nav class="nav">This is where navbar will go</nav>

<section style="background-color:black; width:80%; height:100px;"></section>

<footer class="footer" style="background-color:blue; width:100%">This is the footer</footer>
</div>
```

Here is the example. If I resize my browser on computer the nav scrolls down to right above footer. But on my phone for some reason it will stay right after header???

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the fact that the Safari browser requires the -webkit- prefix for some css rules. Could you try this:

```
.element {order: 1; -webkit-order: 1;}
```

Comment: Tried, but still no result; iPhone displays the DOM exactly as it appears on the page. I want to download Safari on comp to see if it's a browser issue or specifically of the browser release of my phone - it might just be that it's too obsolete, since updates won't run on IOS6.

Comment: Alright, it's definitely just Safari and not the installation on my phone; on comp it did the exact same thing whereas other browsers (Chrome/Chromium, Firefox and IE) all worked fine. Any idea how I can fix this? For now I've cheated and added a second div with the same contents of nav which is only set to display:block at inferior screen resolutions, and that works. But it's not the prettiest of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #layout {
    display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 3;
    -webkit-order:3;
  }
  .nav {
    order: 2;
    -webkit-order:2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
<header style="background-color:red; width:100%; height:100px;">Placeholder</header>

<nav class="nav">This is where navbar will go</nav>

<section style="background-color:black; width:80%; height:100px;"></section>

<footer class="footer" style="background-color:blue; width:100%">This is the footer</footer>
</div>
```

This is the new code as I have it now - but still Safari won't read it and display the nav right under the header at ANY resolution :(